# Problems making div class height 100%

Tags: css, html

I have a problem making a div id to be height 100%, the template what I'm working on it its this:

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fCLDJ/4/)

Code:

```
  <div id="Content">
   <div class="Top"></div>
   <div class="Data">
    <div class="News">
     <div class="Position">
      <span class="Red">News:</span> Try out our updated commentary system! Now you can Reply to any comment and Like the best comments!
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Content">
     <div class="Title_Content">
      <div class="Position">
       Test
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="Bottom"></div>
  </div>
```

The div id what I'm trying to make it 100% its "#Content", hope someone can show me how I can fix that problem?

Comment: But, what do you want? Do you want that div#Content cover the all page vertically?

Comment: am i right when I say you dont want any vertical scroll.But if you go the way you are going,you will end up with a very cluttered page.What exactly do you want??

Comment: @Mihai Viteazu:my suggestion would be to set the height to auto so that content take up their height allowing vertical scroll.

Comment: what i need is div#Content to finish on bottom of page ... so to be 100% height ... i try many ways but didn't success ...

Comment: it seems u want to cover the complete page and wants your footer aka `content` to be at the bottom of page?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set height using `%`, you can use it for `width`.

You can use the `"min-height: 650px;"`.